# Can landmark detection be only used for faces and human bodies?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, convolutional-neural-network, computer-vision

I want to use landmark detection for finding specific points of interest in an indoor setting e.g. bedrooms, bathrooms etc. Is it possible to use it? So far I have only seen landmark detection being used for things like faces or human bodies. Any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: I recommend you these great papers: [Corners for Layout: End-to-End Layout Recovery from 360 Images](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.08094.pdf) and [What’s in my Room? Object Recognition on Indoor Panoramic Images](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.06138.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is totally possible.

> Any suggestions or ideas?

1. You will need to train your own model because you might not find any pre-trained models for the same. (but do check if they are available)
2. Pick any state of the art model and I will suggest choosing the pose estimation models.
3. Collect images and annotate your dataset in the appropriate format using various tools that are available (that the authors of the model used to annotate their dataset).
4. Experiment whether the pre-trained weights of the model are helpful or not. For this, you can try to quickly train the model on a small subset of the dataset.
5. If you are getting good results, train the model using the whole dataset.
6. If you are not getting good results then try increasing data, collecting more images, or changing the model.